# PHP GD poor thumb quality

Tags: php, resize, gd

```
            $tmp_im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
            $x = $this->getX();
            $y = $this->getY();

            $w = floor($resize_height * ($x / $y));
            $h = $resize_height;

            $this->tmp_im = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

                            imagealphablending($this->tmp_im, false);
                            imagesavealpha($this->tmp_im, true);

                            imagecopyresampled($this->tmp_im, $this->im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $this->getX(), $this->getY());

            $this->im = $this->tmp_im;


            $hs = floor(($width - $this->getX())/2);
            $vs = floor(($height - $this->getY())/2);

            imagecopy($tmp_im, $this->im, $hs, $vs, 0, 0, $this->getX(), $this->getY());

            $this->im = $tmp_im;
```

the results is a poor quality resized image, what im doing wrong? i also tried to use a imagejpeg with quality = 100

Comment: There are some strange assignments going on in there, first you create tmp_im, then you create $this->tmp_im, then you assign $this->tmp_im to $this->im, then you assign $tmp_im to $this->im.  So which of these things are you outputting?  Could it be the wrong one, or an incomplete one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`imagecopytruecolor()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) instead of

```
imagecopy($tmp_im, $this->im, $hs, $vs, 0, 0, $this->getX(), $this->getY());
```

This is a Notice on the [official PHP documentation page](http://php.net/manual/function.imagecopyresampled.php):

> There is a problem due to palette image limitations (255+1 colors).
>   Resampling or filtering an image commonly needs more colors than 255,
>   a kind of approximation is used to calculate the new resampled pixel
>   and its color. With a palette image we try to allocate a new color, if
>   that failed, we choose the closest (in theory) computed color. This is
>   not always the closest visual color. That may produce a weird result,
>   like blank (or visually blank) images. To skip this problem, please
>   use a truecolor image as a destination image, such as one created by
>   imagecreatetruecolor().